# JS - Why some applications have multiple handlers for the same POST call?

Tags: javascript, post

I have seen applications which issues the POST to the same URL for both sign in and sign out. The difference is in the service tied to the html element calling the POST . What is the benefit of this coding style? I understand the importance of having same URL for multiple services in SPA but why follow this convention in a non SPA application?

Comment: Why not? I mean, if it's a simple toggle like login/logout is, what's the benefit to having two URLs? Not that *I* would (nor have I ever seen this in an app), but I don't see a huge downside except for slightly-increased endpoint complexity.

Comment: Clearly, technically it works. My take is doesn't it make the code convoluted or hard to debug? What is the upside of this approach?

Comment: Whether or not it's "convoluted" depends entirely on what's being implemented, and how. I'd argue toggles wouldn't benefit much from multiple endpoints, but that depends on what's *actually* being done. There's always a complexity tradeoff, whether it's in the code or in routing or elsewhere. There may be non-technical reasons to use this pattern in an API as well, and whether or not it makes sense also depends on the framework in play, e.g., a framework that supports internal routing of HTTP verbs to known methods makes the endpoints the same, but the handlers different.